# How to stop a Thread running a Handler?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, handler

I have a thread inside a service that listens to a handler for instructions and writes byte[] commands to the Bluetooth stream:

```
class BToutgoingThread extends Thread
{
    private static final String INNER_TAG = "BToutgoingThread";

    public void run() 
    {
        Log.e("Service: BToutgoingThread","Starting");

        this.setName(INNER_TAG);


        Looper.prepare();


        mMyServiceHandler = new Handler()
        {

            public void handleMessage(Message msg)
            {

            // handle messages...
            switch(msg.what)
                {

                case 1: // some message
                    write(reset);
                    break;

                case 2: // some other message
                    write(motReset);
                    break;

                }
            }

        };



        Log.e("outgoing thread","active");


        if(stopOutgoing){       // this is set true in Service onDestroy()
        Log.e("Service: BToutgoingThread","TERMINATED");

        for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++){
        mMyServiceHandler.removeMessages(i);    // remove messages
        }

        mMyServiceHandler.getLooper().quit();   // end the looper
        return;
        }

        Looper.loop();


    }

    public void write(byte[] bytes) {
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)    // 20 rounds, rapid, FIRE!
            {
            mmOutStream.write(bytes);   // bang
            }
        } catch (IOException e) { }
    }


}
```

It works perfectly until I try to stop the thread. I set stopOutgoing true, but that doesn’t do anything. I’ve tried putting the `return;` as a command to be executed by the Handler, but that was equally as useless.

I also don’t get why the Looper doesn’t seem to loop. I should be spamming LogCat and creating infinite new Handlers, but that doesn’t happen.

I’d like to understand why the Looper is working the way it is, but at this point I’d settle for a technique to just end the thread. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: instead of that hard hand work,  use a HandlerThread...

Comment: @pshink How should I implement a HandlerThread in my current code structure?

Comment: You don't implement a HandlerThread, its a ready to use class

Comment: OK, I'll give that a try.